# Using docker agent inside a docker-swarm slave that is running inside Docker as well

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We have a Jenkins file that looks as follow

```
pipeline {
    agent {
      node {
        label 'slave-test'
      }
    }
    stages {
      stage ('test docker run') {
        agent {
          docker {
            image 'node:14.4.0-slim'
            args '-u root -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'
            reuseNode true
          }
        }
        steps {
          sh 'PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD=true npm ci'
          sh 'npm run test:ci'
          sh 'npm run patternlab:build'
        }
      }
    }
```

The node labelled as **slave-test** is a docker-swarm client running as a docker image based on debian-buster. Inside this slave we want to start the image node:14.4.0-slim to run some tests and package some frontend-stuff.

We use reuseNode = true to use the same workspace as agent in the beginning of the pipeline. But Jenkins tells us :

```
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (test docker run)
[Pipeline] getContext
[Pipeline] isUnix
[Pipeline] sh
13:24:07  + docker inspect -f . node:14.4.0-slim
13:24:07  .
[Pipeline] withDockerContainer
13:24:07  hofladen-slave01-20d7912d seems to be running inside container 23d34522985b2e7ec99327337cd2b20bee22018562886c9930a4ba777cda11ca
13:24:07  but /home/****/workspace/ttern-library_feature_BWEBHM-262@2 could not be found among [/var/run/docker.sock]
13:24:07  but /home/****/workspace/ttern-library_feature_BWEBHM-262@2@tmp could not be found among [/var/run/docker.sock]
13:24:07  $ docker run -t -d -u 10000:10000 -u root -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -w /home/****/workspace/ttern-library_feature_BWEBHM-262@2 -v /home/****/workspace/ttern-library_feature_BWEBHM-262@2:/home/****/workspace/ttern-library_feature_BWEBHM-262@2:rw,z -v /home/****/workspace/ttern-library_feature_BWEBHM-262@2@tmp:/home/****/workspace/ttern-library_feature_BWEBHM-262@2@tmp:rw,z -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** node:14.4.0-slim cat
13:24:08  $ docker top 0759f74d1c2676d68a32edab9775b2ca3c518fa2e4e673af856a87e9da514683 -eo pid,comm
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
13:29:15  process apparently never started in /home/****/workspace/ttern-library_feature_BWEBHM-262@2@tmp/durable-504ce105
13:29:15  (running Jenkins temporarily with -Dorg.****ci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.LAUNCH_DIAGNOSTICS=true might make the problem clearer)
[Pipeline] }
13:29:15  $ docker stop --time=1 0759f74d1c2676d68a32edab9775b2ca3c518fa2e4e673af856a87e9da514683
13:29:17  $ docker rm -f 0759f74d1c2676d68a32edab9775b2ca3c518fa2e4e673af856a87e9da514683
[Pipeline] // withDockerContainer
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Cancel running builds if exist)
Stage "Cancel running builds if exist" skipped due to earlier failure(s)
```

We need to run these commands all in the same Jenkins Workspace in order to perform the later steps.

Does anybody have an Idea how to achive this. We know that the pipeline runs fine if the pipeline is not running on an agent that is on a standalone machine.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by starting jenkins slave as container with a volume to share data and allow access to /var/run/docker.sock

```
#!/bin/bash
volume_name=myfinevolume-slave01-workspace
docker volume create ${volume_name}
docker run -d --name jenkins-agent-for-myfineproject \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:rw \
  --mount source=${volume_name},target=/home/jenkins/workspace \
  --memory=8G \
  --memory-swap=16G \
  --restart unless-stopped \
  myfineregsitry.domain.lala/acme/jenkins-swarm-client:3.17.0_buster
```